# How QEventLoop must be used when we don't subclass QThread in Qt 4.8x?

Tags: qt, qthread, qeventloop

I've read there are two approaches for working with QThread.
If I have a Worker class, which inherits QObject (as in http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), then how should I create and manage local QEventLoop for working with signals/slots? I don't want to have memory leaks. 
How QNetworkAccessManager should be created in worker described in http://codethis.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/using-qthread-without-subclassing/?

Comment: QThread starts it's own event loop when you call it's [start()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#start) function. [This should be a good read](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects#64a093776750c691afdeb133a80f55e2).

Comment: OK, and how QNetworkAccessManager should be created in worker described in http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/?

Comment: `QNetworkAccessManager` is asynchronous, so I don't know why you need it in a different thread, but it's no different than creating it in your main thread. Create it like you would do it in any other class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't subclass `QThread`, it has its own event loop [(Fixed QThread documentation of Qt 5, also appliccable for Qt 4)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#details):

> By default, run() starts the event loop by calling exec() and runs a Qt event loop inside the thread.

Managing the work done by the worker can be easily done using signals & slots:

> (...) you are free to connect the Worker's slots to any signal, from any object, in any thread. It is safe to connect signals and slots across different threads, thanks to a mechanism called queued connections.

This means you usually don't need to care about any event loop on your own (unless you require special behaviour). Simply connect the thread's `started` signal to any slot of your worker object and make sure you set up some kind of deletion chain: Either the worker emits a signal which leads to the thread being stopped and deleted, or the other way round - both ways work, depending on your situation.